# how to backup and restore azure document DB AZURE

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need to backup and restore DocumentDB in Azure. I have used DocumentDB Data Migration Tool v1.7 for backup in local and blob I have done, here is the URL for Automatic online backup and restore with DocumentDB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-online-backup-and-restore . Any documentation for real time backup and restore for document DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out this blog post:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/backing-up-documentdb-databases/

It covers the backup strategy you are using with the Migration Tool, plus the "Double Writes" strategy of having a secondary documentDB in a different region in case of outage or restore needed.